# Сообщение через сайт на WhatsApp

Tags: php, jquery, whatsapp, sendmessage

Нужна такая фича как отправить себе на WhatsApp. Допустим человек просматривает страницу товара на моем сайте и ему понравилась какая-то вещь, но у него нету постоянного доступа в сеть интернет и там кок раз таки стоит кнопка отправить себе на вотсап. А в самом тексте сообщения должно быть описание товара с фотографией. Возможно ли такое? Если возможно то как реализовать через php или js,jquery одно из 3? Номер вотсапа указывается при регистрации

Answer (score 1):

Такое возможно.  Смотрите документацию. https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/26000030/?category=5245251
Вообще ваш запрос сейчас выглядит как задача на fl.ru

Поднялось настроение после прочтения:

> и там кок раз таки